# Which is the latest 32-bit Python?

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

May I know which version is the latest 32-bit Python?

I am currently using Python 2.7.4 and it is 64-bit. Since msvc11 is 32-bit and I need to write Python extentions in C++, thus I have to install a 32-bit Python. There is a list of python installers at python website. Which one can meet my needs?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The Windows SDK contains a 64-bit compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're talking about an installer, I suppose you're using Windows (usually there's no installers for Linux, only package managers which are different things).

You can find the latest releases on [Python's download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/).